# Start oracle dequeue on startup

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-aq

I got the following error of Oracle,

```
ORA-25226: dequeue failed, queue string.string is not enabled for dequeue
```

And the following is the Cause and Action for it from the official document:

```
Cause: The queue has not been enabled for dequeue.
Action: Enable the queue using START_QUEUE.
```

But this error occurs every time when restart the database, is there any configuration to set to start the dequeue on database startup?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is the status of the queue in dba_queues

```
select owner,name,enqueue_enabled,dequeue_enabled from dba_queues;
```

If the queue is disabled, then start it with

```
begin
 dbms_aqadm.start_queue(queue_name => '<OWNER.QUEUE_NAME>');
end; /
```

I believe this should persist across restarts, I haven't tested though.

Comment: Yes,it's still enable after restart. Maybe because I have just started the enqueue only.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by the lack of

```
DECLARE 
   subscriber          sys.aq$_agent; 
BEGIN 
   subscriber := sys.aq$_agent('subscriber1', '<OWNER.QUEUE_NAME>', null); 
   DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(
      queue_name         => '<OWNER.QUEUE_NAME>', 
      subscriber         =>  subscriber); 
END;
```

It's [all boilerplate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_admin.htm#i1008642) and it allows me to actually receive messages.